# Python - Sphinx adding image gives error

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In chapter1.rst, I have the following:

```
TEST
****

* Test1 

.. image:: ../images/snap.png
```

When I run **sphinx-build** (Sphinx 1.0.7), I get this error:

> Exception occurred: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 70, in join path += '/' + b
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128) "

Comment: If you still need help, please provide more details. How can the problem be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the full path of ../images/snap.png contain no ASCII char.
Change you project path to an English only path and try again.